# Download PDF File from API Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a console application that

1. Connects to a vendor API to pull voucher numbers for submitted expenses between two dates and
2. Downloads a PDF copy of receipts submitted with the expense

The first part, I have working fine. I am able to connect to the Vendor API and parse out the returned XML to create an array of voucher numbers (needed to get the PDF images) using the following code:

```
static async Task RunAsyncCR()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"un","SomeUser"},
                    {"pw","SomePassword"},
                    {"method","getVoucherInvoices"},
                    {"fromDate","05/30/2016"},
                    {"toDate", "06/13/2016"}
                };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");

                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.chromeriver.com/receipts/doit", content);

                Console.WriteLine("Connected...");

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                char[] DelimiterChars = {'<'};

                String[] xmlReturn = responseString.Split(DelimiterChars);

                string[] VoucherNumber = new string[500];

                int i = 0;

                foreach (string s in xmlReturn)
                {
                    if (s.Contains("voucherInvoice>") && s != "/voucherInvoice>\n    ")
                    {
                        VoucherNumber[i] = s.Substring(15, 16);

                        i++;
                    }
                }

                Array.Resize(ref VoucherNumber, i);
```

Yes, there is likely a better way of doing this, but it works and returns the values I am expecting.

Now, what I am having trouble with, is when I connect back to the API to retrieve the file, I cannot seem to be able to download the file to a specified file path.

I can connect back to the API using

```
            i = 0;

            foreach (string x in VoucherNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Get receipt: " + x);

                var NewValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"un","SomeUser"},
                    {"pw","SomePassword"},
                    {"method","getReceiptsWithCoverPage"},
                    {"voucherInvoiceForPdf", VoucherNumber[i]}
                };

                var NewContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(NewValues);

                var NewResponse = await client.PostAsync("https://www.chromeriver.com/receipts/doit", NewContent);

                string NewResponseString = await NewResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But I cannot seem to write the response to a valid file (PDF)

Here is a screen shot of my Autos window as I step through the code, where I would need to download the file:

[image: Autos]

**My question is, from this point, how do I go about saving the file to my system?**

I have tried to take the encoded response I get from doing `Console.WriteLine(NewResponseString);` and write it to a file using the `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()` method, using a specified filepath/name, but this results in a blank file. I have also spent some time researching the depths of Google/Stackoverflow, but do not understand how to implement the results I find.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the first ~20 bytes of that stream in hex here?

Comment: Do you have experience working with Streams? If not that is where you should start. If that is not your question maybe you can clarify - do you need help saving a stream to disk or do you need help extracting the stream/byte array from the response?

Comment: @Igor - I have no experience working with streams - this is the first time I have ever needed to connect to an API to retrieve a file...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I think you need help with Streams. The returned `HttpContent` is actually a `System.Net.Http.StreamContent` instance which shows that you are getting content back. Its just a matter of getting the Stream (content) from that instance and saving that to a file.

```
var NewResponse = await client.PostAsync("https://www.chromeriver.com/receipts/doit", NewContent);

System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = NewResponse.Content; // actually a System.Net.Http.StreamContent instance but you do not need to cast as the actual type does not matter in this case

using(var file = System.IO.File.Create("somePathHere.pdf")){ // create a new file to write to
    var contentStream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); // get the actual content stream
    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(file); // copy that stream to the file stream
}
```

---

I respectfully recommend that you do a little reading on how Streams work. This is a common construct in many languages that you will probably have to deal with again in the near future.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I will do a little reading as soon as time allows for it (too much to do, too little time).

Comment: @Igor, Why do you do `Flush` operation? Is not it redundant?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are you sure there is a file to begin with? May I suggest using the open source library PdfSharp. I personally use it myself and it works great. As far as downloading the file, maybe this may help you...

Download Synchronously

```
using System.Net;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\\myfile.txt");
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a file there, if you look at my screen shot, it contains the file information, including the name of the file being returned.

Comment: If you want to go the PdfSharp route, here is the link for the download.. and below is a sample of mine on how to implement the writing of the pdf..

http://www.pdfsharp.net/Downloads.ashx

Comment: PdfDocument test = new PdfDocument ();

test.Info.Title = "testing PDF";

PdfPage page = test.AddPage ();

XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage (page);

XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);

graph.DrawString(strPairs, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, 

page.Width.Point, page.Height.Point), XStringFormats.Center);

string pdfFilename = "testPairs.pdf";

test.Save(pdfFilename);

Process.Start(pdfFilename);

Comment: The content being returned is a pdf structure. The OP just does not know how to save that content to disk. A pdf library would not help at all with this unless the OP also needs help creating PDF files programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

At first Create StreamReader from NewResponse

```
Stream receiveStream = NewResponse.GetResponseStream ();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Then Define a StremaWriter to write into a file.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\MyNewFile.pdf", append: false))
{
    writer.Write(readStream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Alternative Approach is

```
var httpContent = NewResponse.Content; 

using(var newFile = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\MyNewFile.pdf"))
{ 
    var stream = await httpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    await stream.CopyToAsync(newFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, did not find any other solution that satisfied my situation:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())

{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "someapikey");
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://someurl.com");
  byte[] bytes = client.GetByteArrayAsync(client.BaseAddress).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  
  string pdfFilePath = @"c:\somepath"
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, bytes);

  //Note that below is only to open PDF in standard viewer, not necessary
  var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName=pdfFilePath,
    WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pdfFilePath),
    UseShellExecute = true
}

  process.StartInfo = startInfo;
  process.Start();

}
```

Comment: What if few users call this method simultaneously? Won't `c:\somepath` be overwritten and thus potentially corrupted/another resource?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for download a pdf from the API. It will convert the string data to bytes and provide you the necessary solution.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URL);

request.ContentType = "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8";
request.Method = "GET";

using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse()) {

    BinaryReader bin = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    byte[] buffer = bin.ReadBytes((Int32) response.ContentLength);

    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=+ filename); 

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

    Response.Flush();

    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I like seeing contributions from new participants, but it I'd encourage you to test your solution before posting. This doesn't compile, let alone work. I'd suggest fixing it so it works. It could end up being a valuable answer to this question.