# Download file with WebClient or HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpclient, webclient

I am trying to download file from a URL and I have to choose between WebClient and HttpClient. I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient) article and several other articles on the internet. Everywhere, it is suggested to go for HttpClient due to its great async support and other .Net 4.5 privileges. But I am still not totally convinced and need more inputs.

I am using below code to download file from internet:

**WebClient:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, filePath);
```

**HttpClient:**

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{        
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
    }
}
```

From my perspective, I can see only one disadvantage in using WebClient, that would be the non async call, blocking the calling thread. But what if I am not worried about the blocking of thread or use `client.DownloadFileAsync()` to leverage the async support?

On the other hand, if I use HttpClient, ain't I loading every single byte of a file into memory and then writing it to a local file? If the file size is too large, won't memory overhead be expensive? Which could be avoided if we use WebClient, since it will directly write to local file and not consume system memory.

So, if performance is my utter priority, which approach should I use for download? I would like to be clarified if my above assumption is wrong, and I am open to alternate approach as well.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799419/download-pdf-file-from-api-using-c-sharp help?

Comment: Also see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient .

Comment: There is one more issue with WebClient: It won't work in .NET Core.

Comment: "disadvantage in using WebClient...the non async call, blocking the calling thread" So use [`DownloadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: WebClient is obsolete sincd 2012 and the two snippets are doing different things. You can use [HttpClient.GetStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get a stream to the file in one line and then use `.CopyToAsync()` to copy the stream's contents to a file stream

Comment: `ain't I loading every single byte of a file into memory` no, unless you explicitly ask for this with `GetByteArrayAsync`

Comment: @KennethK. you probably mean [DownloadFileTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?view=netframework-4.7.2). The older [DownloadFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) uses events to notify that a download completed, it's not asynchronous in the sense used nowadays

Answer (score 71):

You can do it natively with .Net 4.5+.  I tried doing it your way and then I just found a method in Intellisense that seemed to make sense.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
uri = new Uri(generatePdfsRetrieveUrl + pdfGuid + ".pdf");
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
using (var fs = new FileStream(
    HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/Downloads/{0}.pdf", pdfGuid)), 
    FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this, note `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/Downloads/{0}.pdf", pdfGuid)),` can be replaced with an arbitrary path.

Comment: Shouldn't `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` and `var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);` be in using statements?  It says they inherit IDisposable.

Comment: @Trisped You can, but depending on your usage you should consider that when a client is disposed the port will be left in a `TIME_WAIT` state. See [here](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Doesn't the C# 8.0 automatically dispose of disposable objects when they go out of scope?

Comment: @Bluebaron no, you have to use `using (xxx) { ... }` or `using var xxx = ...;` to dispose it after the end of the scope.

Comment: Microsoft's own documentation recommends only having one HttpClient for the entire lifetime of your application. To prevent SocketExceptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#instancing. So it is considered good practice to not have a using statement to dispose the client, despite it implementing IDisposable.

Comment: If I am downloading a very large file (30GB), will it read all 30GB to memory before writing the file to disk? Or will it read and write in chunks?

Comment: @BenPhung, I'm almost certain it will flush to disk automatically in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 30):

To use HttpClient on my existing code that used WebClient, I wrote a small extension method to use it on the same way I used `DownloadFileTaskAsync` on my code.

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) // WebClient
{
    var fileName = @"C:\temp\imgd.jpg";
    var uri = new Uri("https://yourwebsite.com/assets/banners/Default.jpg");

    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, fileName);
}
```

To use it we can have this extension method:

```
public static class HttpClientUtils
{
    public static async Task DownloadFileTaskAsync(this HttpClient client, Uri uri, string FileName)
    {
        using (var s = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri))
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await s.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Here is my approach.

If you are calling a WebApi to get a file, then from a controller method you can use HttpClient GET request and return file stream using FileStreamResult return type.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAttachment(int FileID)
{
    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
    uriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
    uriBuilder.Host = "api.example.com";

    var Path = "/files/download";
    uriBuilder.Path = Path;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", access_token); //if any
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriBuilder.ToString());

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = response.Content;
                var contentStream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); // get the actual content stream
                return File(contentStream, content_type, filename);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not use the HttpClient as a Disposable object although it is, you will get socket exhaustion if you have many requests. Use the httpClient has a static instance instead, lots of articles online covering this problem.

Comment: It should also not be used as a `static` instance @RuiLima, but managed through the `HttpClientFactory`. The static instance can also cause problems as it is never refreshed.

Comment: Where do you specify the remote file? 

Answer (score 6):

For code being called repeatedly, you **do not** want to put `HttpClient` in a `using` block ([it will leave hanging ports open](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/))

For downloading a file with HttpClient, I found [this extension method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/02/17/httpclient-downloading-to-a-local-file/) which seemed like a good and reliable solution to me:

```
public static class HttpContentExtensions
{
    public static Task ReadAsFileAsync(this HttpContent content, string filename, bool overwrite)
    {
        string pathname = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
        if (!overwrite && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("File {0} already exists.", pathname));
        }

        FileStream fileStream = null;
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream(pathname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            return content.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ContinueWith(
                (copyTask) =>
                {
                    fileStream.Close();
                });
        }
        catch
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here’s one way to use it to download a URL and save it to a file](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/how-to-download-a-file-with-httpclient-in-c/): (I am using windows 7, therefore no WindowsRT available to me, so I’m also using System.IO.)

```
public static class WebUtils
{
    private static Lazy<IWebProxy> proxy = new Lazy<IWebProxy>(() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.WebProxyAddress) ? null : new WebProxy { Address = new Uri(Settings.Default.WebProxyAddress), UseDefaultCredentials = true });

    public static IWebProxy Proxy
    {
        get { return WebUtils.proxy.Value; }
    }

    public static Task DownloadAsync(string requestUri, string filename)
    {
        if (requestUri == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(“requestUri”);

        return DownloadAsync(new Uri(requestUri), filename);
    }

    public static async Task DownloadAsync(Uri requestUri, string filename)
    {
        if (filename == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");

        if (Proxy != null)
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = Proxy;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
            {
                using (Stream contentStream = await (await httpClient.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, Constants.LargeBufferSize, true))
                {
                    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that code is saving the address of the proxy server I use (at work) in a setting, and using that if such setting is specified. Otherwise, it should tell you all you need to know regarding using the HttpClient beta to download and save a file.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient may be worth a read.

Comment: Most of this code isn't related to the question. HttpClient instances *shouldn't* be disposed immediately either.

Answer (score 4):

If you want (or have) to do this synchronously, but using the nice HttpClient class, then there's this simple approach:

```
string requestString = @"https://example.com/path/file.pdf";

var GetTask = httpClient.GetAsync(requestString);
GetTask.Wait(WebCommsTimeout); // WebCommsTimeout is in milliseconds

if (!GetTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // write an error
    return;
}
                    
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\path\file.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    var ResponseTask = GetTask.Result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
    ResponseTask.Wait(WebCommsTimeout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is very simple. Using `FileStream` you can store it in the local folder, or return it from API using `FileStreamResult`.
Example for store into local folder:

```
private async Task SaveDataIntoLocalFolder(string url,string fileName)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
           var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
           using (var fileStream = fileInfo.OpenWrite())
           {
              await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
           }
        }
        else
        {
          throw new Exception("File not found");
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: The line `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` may result to a successfully completed task that hasn't done the job it was supposed to do. `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` should be preferable. Also the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, you are right. But response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() throws exception for an unsuccessful operation. HttpClient can be used in many ways, this is just a demo code. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple demo UWP application for downloading an image file.
Just paste the image URL link and press the download button. You can identify the file type and change the `fileName` to download the desired file.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="HttpDownloader.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HttpDownloader"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="uriInput"
                     Header="URI:" PlaceholderText="Please provide an uri"
                     Width="300"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="Dowload"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.xs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using System.Threading;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace HttpDownloader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string imageUrl = uriInput.Text;
            try
            {
                using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(50000))
                {
                    var uri = new Uri(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(imageUrl));
                    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationTokenSource.Token))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        var mediaType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
                        if (mediaType.IndexOf("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                            || mediaType.IndexOf("jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            fileName += ".jpg";
                        }
                        else if (mediaType.IndexOf("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            fileName += ".png";
                        }
                        else if (mediaType.IndexOf("gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            fileName += ".gif";
                        }
                        else if (mediaType.IndexOf("bmp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            fileName += ".bmp";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileName += ".png";
                        }

                        // Get the app's local folder.
                        StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

                        // Create a new subfolder in the current folder.
                        // Replace the folder if already exists.
                        string desiredName = "Images";
                        StorageFolder newFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                        StorageFile newFile = await newFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                        using (Stream streamStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(newFile.Path, FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                await streamStream.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occur");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will find the image in this folder.

`Users/[current user name]/AppData/Local/Packages/[Application package name]/LocalState/Images`

Comment: Using `HttpClient` like that is an [extremely dangerous practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client) that can lead to port exhaustion. See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#instancing).

Comment: Thanks, @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine for your suggestion. Next, I will implement it using SocketsHttpHandler and PooledConnectionLifetime.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: which approach should I use for download?

Use HTTPClient class because WebClient class is Obsolete. This is also recommended by Microsoft itself.
See: [microsoft webclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks)  and  [microsoft warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0014)

In addition, Thymine's answer is very valuable. The [website he links](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) contains, in my opinion, the clearest, neatest, and best application in code.
This is because it takes into account the fact that HttpClient variable must be used as a shared resource to avoid the mentioned SocketException. So it doesn't use"using" for client.

And it is the simplest example that downloads an image to a file.
The question was not to create a separate function for this, Thymine's code is very complete if one is looking for that, look at his response to that

Below is the code from the website, slightly modified for the purpose of downloading an image.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
        {
            var uri = new Uri("https://yourwebsite.com/the_image.jpg");
            var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            using (var fs = new FileStream("FileName", FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   HttpClient _client=new HttpClient();
   byte[] buffer = null;
   try
   {       
      HttpResponseMessage task = await _client.GetAsync("https://**FILE_URL**");
      Stream task2 = await task.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        await task2.CopyToAsync(ms);
        buffer = ms.ToArray();
      }
      File.WriteAllBytes("C:/**PATH_TO_SAVE**", buffer);  
   }
   catch
   {

   }
```