# Download a file with HttpClient but defer writing

Tags: c#, .net-core, download, httpclient

I can download byte[]'s and write them to a file no problem, [much link this link does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711428/download-file-with-webclient-or-httpclient). But when I make a simple alteration, saving the bytes[] and readCount to a List and then foreach over the list, I get a corrupt file.

Below is partial code that shows what I mean. There are two commented paths: one stores the bytes/counts (and order) and then writes when the reading is complete. The other writes in line with the each read.

Because of the order field, I have verified that the foreach is writing the bytes in the correct order but the partial code listing doesn't explicitly use it.

```
    private class ByteHolder
    {
        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; } = new byte[8192];
        public int BytesRead { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
    }

    var byteList = new List<ByteHolder>();

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_fileBytes.SavingPath.RuntimePath(), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
    {
        do
        {
            var bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {

                //--- WRITING THE bytes and counts this way produces corrupt file -->
                var offset = 0;
                foreach (var byteHolder in byteList)
                {
                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(byteHolder.Buffer, offset, byteHolder.BytesRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    offset += 8192;
                }

                isMoreToRead = false;
                FileDownloadComplete?.Invoke(this, _fileBytes);
                continue;
            }

            //--- Storing them in this class and list for writing above DOES NOT WORK -->
            byteList.Add(new ByteHolder() { Buffer = buffer, BytesRead = bytesRead, Order = readCount }); 

            //--- Writing inline with the read WORKS -->
            //await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            readCount++;
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
```

Comment: So you always writing data into file from offset 0, you need to increment offset within "foreach" loop.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the offset to the sample code above. It still generates a corrupt file. Not sure if I should offset by the buffer size or the read size, but neither works. The file I'm working with is an xlsx. (Also, the inline WriteAsync uses offset 0 and it works!?) The particular xlsx takes four reads to download.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for WriteAsync, the offset you pass in is the offset in the *buffer*, not the file. It should always be 0; the increment is unnecessary.

Comment: Where is `buffer` initialized? Here you are reusing the same buffer array on every loop which is what is causing the issue. You have to create a new buffer array every time you read.

Comment: Mike Zboray, "create a new buffer every time I read" is the answer. Thanks so much! That isn't a very obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach (var byteHolder in byteList)
            {
                var offset = 0;
                await fileStream.WriteAsync(byteHolder.Buffer, offset, byteHolder.BytesRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                offset += 8192;
            }
```

You're always writing at offset 0, no matter which `byteHolder` instance you're processing at the time.

Comment: Your whole algorithm is wrong anyway, you shouldn't keep the whole thing in memory before writing it to disk, just write the pieces you get as you're getting them.

Comment: I've tried this every way. Blindy noticed a problem. I fixed it. Same problem. I cannot do what you suggest because ultimately this file will be transferred over SignalR which cannot handle bytes. Before you call foul on that, I've already verified I can transfer Base64 representations over SignalR without error. The problem happens before SignalR anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's transferred over, you're using an operating system construct called a socket. It doesn't even matter what you think "cannot handle bytes" means, (tcp) sockets stream bytes to you in chunks of the size you request.

Comment: I wish that were true. It would have saved me a few days. Yet, when I SendAsync a List<byte[]>, it never triggers the .On. I change that call to send a string and the .On fires.