# Using HttpWebRequest/Response To Download A Binary (.exe) File From A Web Server?

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, filestream, httpwebresponse

I am writing a program that needs to download an .exe file from a website and then save it to the hard drive.
After many web searches and fumbling through examples here is the code I have come up with so far:

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link to my.exe);
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();               
        string tempFilePath = someLocation;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath))
        {
            int size = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (size > 0)
            {
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                size = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        fileStream.Flush();
        fileStream.Close();
```

I keep seeing the following error:

```
Exception: System.NotSupportedException: This stream does not support seek operations.     at System.Net.ConnectStream.get_Length()
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: I'd sugges to use HttpClient instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711428/download-file-with-webclient-or-httpclient for a complete example.

Comment: I need to use httpwebresponse/request here.

Comment: try ``responseStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin)`` before using it.

Comment: doesnt seem to help

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```cs
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link to my.exe);
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();               
string tempFilePath = someLocation;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath))
{
     responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
fileStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
```