# Direct download of the audio file(web url) without playing in the browser in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, download

I want to have a link on the page **(asp.net 5)** that points to an audio file on the web, actually on my download site. Now when the link is clicked, it starts playing in a new window, which I don't want. But I want to start downloading. I also use the download tag, but it doesn't work. Maybe it is because the link is outside the domain of the site.
If I use the following codes, the file will be downloaded, but the problem here is that nothing will be displayed to the user until the end of the download, and after the end of the download, the downloaded file will be seen at once, and this may mislead the user.
In fact, I want the download to start normally and the user to see the download process.

```
var net = new System.Net.WebClient();
            var data = net.DownloadData("https://myDownloadSite/file.mp3");
            var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
            var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
            var fileName = "file.mp3";
            return File(content, contentType, fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download by using **anchorTag**

```
<a href="https://myDownloadSite/file.mp3" download>
  Download
</a>
```

**Or you can use below code for return file in .net core**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download() 
{
        Stream stream = await {{__get_stream_based__}}

        if(stream == null)
            return NotFound(); // returns a NotFoundResult with Status404NotFound response.

        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream"); // returns a FileStreamResult
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734137/12777835)

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not paid attention to my explanation and this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the file is too small and the download rate is high, so the process cannot be seen.

**First:**

Under the premise of ensuring that your code can correctly download the file you want, you can change the file transfer rate to see if the browser's download prompt box pops up during the download process.

DevTools -> Network -> Custom transfer rate:
[image]

[image]

**Second:**

If you still can't pop up the download prompt box after changing the transfer rate, you can use JavaScript to call it:

```
<script>
    window.open('/Home/Index', 'DownloadWindowName');
</script>
```

**Third:**

You can also refer to [Abdul Saleem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29185200/18789859) to add a progress bar.

Hope this can help you, good luck.