# c# - Migrate code from WebClient to HTTPClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

```
if (FileExtension == ".txt")
{
    string enumLines = File.ReadAllText(FoundPics, Encoding.UTF8);
    Clipboard.SetText(enumLines);
    using (WebClient client = new())
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FoundPics);
        client.DownloadFile(enumLines, FolderPath + @"\" + "Template.gif");
        Image gifTemplate = Image.FromFile(FolderPath + @"\" + "Template.gif");
        pictureBox.Image = gifTemplate;
    }
}
```

I have this code that retrieves a url from a txt file, downloads a `.gif` from it and sets it to the picturebox
However it's using `Webclient` that I was recommended to avoid.
I'm trying to change to `HTTPClient` now but I'm really lost.
Can someone provide some pseudo code so that I can figure out what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file with WebClient or HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711428/download-file-with-webclient-or-httpclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data  = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(FolderPath + @"\" + "Template.gif");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"\path\to\downloads\Template.gif", data);
```

1. FolderPath must be a uri
2. Your application must have write access to the downloads folder