# How can I download an mp3 file from url (Youtube url or some mp3 url) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, url, download, mp3

This is the code I have been using. It downloads the file, but it cannot be played later. The error I get is that the file is corrupt. I have been using urls from different websites, one of them being Soundcloud.

```
public void SaveMP3()
{
string url = "URL"; // Replace with the actual URL of the MP3 file

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Download the MP3 file and save it to a local path
                client.DownloadFile(url, "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Downloads\\file3.mp3");
                Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error downloading file: " + ex.Message);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Chances are that you are in fact not downloading a file but a html error message. Look through the resulting file with a (hex) editor to inspect its contents.

Comment: Why are you using WebClient? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: @Alex Kemper you are right, I am indeed downloading html (btw, it works completely fine if I'm downloading a pdf). How can I fix this so that I get mp3 from a Soundcloud or YouTube url?  Thanks!

Comment: @FilipCordas pdfs and similar files are being downloaded just fine, it's mp3 and mp4 files that represent an issue. I have tried writing the same code using HttpClient class, but it didn't work right (I probably made some mistakes, this is the first time I am attempting to write a code to download files).

Comment: @StrivingProgrammer I recommend trying it with HttpClient as WebClient is depreciated. It's simple enough https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270371/6330636

Comment: You can try the following regular expression to get the tags of the web page: <a(\\s+(href=\"(?<url>([^\"])*)\"|'([^'])*'|\\w+=\"(([^\"])*)\"|'([^'])*'))+>(?<text>(.*?))</a>