Programmatically read data / click links / download files from webpage?
I'm looking for a way to programmatically read text / click links (which downloads files) from a webpage, preferably with C# but really any solution is fine as long as it works on Windows.
Some context:
I have a dash-cam which I'm looking to save the video files to my NAS when I park car in my garage. I did some messing around with this last night. When I enable the camera WiFi, I can connect my machine to it and browse to the camera's web interface which allows me to view and download video files.


If I can programmatically get data from this webpage, I can set something up to copy the files to my NAS.
I also tried using PuTTy to connect to the dash-cam, but I could never get anything working, even after trying all the different settings, e.g. SSH, Telnet, etc.

Not surprisingly, there is no documentation from Rove on this specific functionality, since this is not the intended way to see the files.
I saw some similar questions on this site such as this one, but most are very old, I figured there might be new options nowadays. After doing a bit more reading, I found that this is call "web-scraping". But most questions such as this one are either very old (13 years old at time of posting this question) or don't have much activity. Are there any recommended NuGet packages for example that can accomplish this?

P.S. Extra info for those interested... Unfortunately the camera's WiFi needs to be turned on manually, and additionally, it won't record video while WiFi is turned on. So I will never have a fully automatic solution (i.e. files upload without any interaction). The theoretical best I can get with this method is: After I park car in garage and turn off car, camera will shut off automatically. I can manually turn camera back on (it has a battery that will last a few minutes), turn Wi-Fi on, and hopefully the battery lasts long enough to allow the files to upload. This is better than needing to manually plug camera into PC to copy files. Not as good as "fully" automatic solution such as uploading to cloud, but that is more expensive and besides I prefer to keep the footage on my personal devices.

I am not familiar with newer frameworks, but just so you know that doing so (specially looking at the web page you want to scrape - which HTML is very simple) with HtmlAgilityPack will consist of very few lines of code. It's all a matter of finding the selector of the html element you want to manipulate (in your case, looks like you want the anchor (link) elements). You then will just need to extract their "href" attributes to get the files they point to and you can download/upload these files where ever you want.

once you have the urls from the parser, you can use something like this to download: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270371/2932782
